# Function in DLL is incorrectly marked dllimport

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

I created a DLL project called Test Lib:

```
// main.h
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    DLL_EXPORT void print();
}
#endif

// main.cpp
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>

#define BUILD_DLL

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

extern "C" {
    DLL_EXPORT void print() {
        cout << "Success" << endl;

        return;
    }
}
```

Above code is from following an example I found online that I could understand. When I try to compile and/or build it, I get the following error & warning:

```
error: function 'void print()' definition is marked dllimport
In function 'void print()':
warning: 'void print()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored
```

This is the second library I'm ever creating because I'm trying to replicate a problem in the first one, when this happened. What is wrong? I'm using Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define `BUILD_DLL` before you include the header file `main.h`.

```
#define BUILD_DLL
#include "main.h"
```

As it stands in your program, you declare `print` with `__declspec(dllimport)` because the header file is processed when `BUILD_DLL` is not defined.